Lag by n rows over specific columns while extending the lenght of dataframe
I am trying to shift down (lag) specific columns in a data frame by n rows (e.g. 2 rows). I have only found posts on lagging over specific columns by 1 row. Here is some mock data.
df <- data.frame(
  A = seq(1,7), 
  B = seq(8,14),
  C = seq(15,21),
  D = seq(22,28)
)

df

> df
 A  B  C  D
 1  8 15 22
 2  9 16 23
 3 10 17 24
 4 11 18 25
 5 12 19 26
 6 13 20 27
 7 14 21 28

What I would like to do here is to shift down the values in columns A, C, and D by n rows and add new rows to my dataframe to create a different dataframe. An example of the desired output with a 2-row lag would look like this.
> df.lag.example
  A  B  C  D
 NA  8 NA NA
 NA  9 NA NA
  1 10 15 22
  2 11 16 23
  3 12 17 24
  4 13 18 25
  5 14 19 26
  6 NA 20 27
  7 NA 21 28


library(dplyr)

rbind(df, df[0,][rep(NA, 2),]) %>% 
  mutate(across(-2, ~lag(., 2))) %>% 
  `rownames<-`(NULL)

#>    A  B  C  D
#> 1 NA  8 NA NA
#> 2 NA  9 NA NA
#> 3  1 10 15 22
#> 4  2 11 16 23
#> 5  3 12 17 24
#> 6  4 13 18 25
#> 7  5 14 19 26
#> 8  6 NA 20 27
#> 9  7 NA 21 28

Created on 2024-04-18 with reprex v2.0.2

Here's something quick and dirty:
foo <- function(df, n, lag_cols) {
  result <- df[c(rep(NA, n), 1L:(nrow(df))), ]
  non_lag_cols <- setdiff(names(df), lag_cols)
  result[non_lag_cols] <- lapply(
    result[(n+1):(nrow(result)), non_lag_cols, drop=FALSE], 
    \(x) c(x, rep(NA, n))
  )
  return(result)
}

foo(df, 2, c("A", "C", "D"))


#       A  B  C  D
# NA   NA  8 NA NA
# NA.1 NA  9 NA NA
# 1     1 10 15 22
# 2     2 11 16 23
# 3     3 12 17 24
# 4     4 13 18 25
# 5     5 14 19 26
# 6     6 NA 20 27
# 7     7 NA 21 28


Here is an small function (that really just generalizes the solution given by @M--) where you can use tidy-selection to pick columns. You can also specify the direction (dir) "down" or "up" and number (n) of shifts:
library(dplyr)

shift <- function(data, cols, dir = "down", ...) {
  dir <- match.arg(dir, c("down", "up"))
  f <- if (dir == "down") list(lag, lead) else list(lead, lag)
  bind_cols(transmute(data, across({{cols}}, ~ f[[1]](.x, ...))),
            transmute(data, across(!{{cols}}, ~ f[[2]](.x, ...)))) |> 
    select(all_of(names(data)))
}

n is passed to lag()/lead() via ....
Usage
shift(df, c(A, C, D), n = 2) # default shift "down"
#    A  B  C  D
# 1 NA  8 NA NA
# 2 NA  9 NA NA
# 3  1 10 15 22
# 4  2 11 16 23
# 5  3 12 17 24
# 6  4 13 18 25
# 7  5 14 19 26
# 8  6 NA 20 27
# 9  7 NA 21 28

# Same as above, but shows some tidy selection
shift(df, -B, n = 2)
shift(df, c(A, C:D), n = 2)
shift(df, matches("^(A|C|D)"), n = 2)

Note: transmute() has been superseded by mutate(..., .keep = "none") and can easily be substituted.
